# How to vertically align an SVG related to a text with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap, I cannot get an inline SVG to vertically center relative to a text. This is what a minimal example looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  />
  </head>
  <body">
    <div style="background-color: lightgrey;" class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <svg height="16" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
          </svg>
      </div>
      <div style="text-transform: uppercase;" class="col pl-0">test</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Zooming at 500% shows that the SVG is not centered but slightly lower than what it should be. For some reason, removing !doctype makes it centered perfectly on both firefox and chrome. It also looks like doubling the SVG size (to 32) makes it work. I'm a bit lost as to how either doctype or the SVG size should affect the vertical alignment though. What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure it has nothing to do with `!doctype` and you just need to add `d-flex` class to the `div`, that wrapped around your `svg`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color: lightgrey;" class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="d-flex col-auto">
        <svg height="16" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
          </svg>
      </div>
      <div style="text-transform: uppercase;" class="col pl-0">test</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```